# Where can I find open data on healthcare quality indicators?

Tags: data-request, medical

I've been working with HEDIS measures for quality measurement in healthcare in the US, but most of what I have seen is proprietary. I'm interested in reproducible research hence my need for open data. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Are you looking for a specific type of provider or at least hospital/physician?

Comment: So far I have worked with only Hospital level data from AHRQ. Unfortunately this data is proprietary. As I explore this topic for my dissertation I would like to favor more publicly available data. Any level (geo-unit/hospital/physician/patient) could work for me.

Comment: I added some places to start for sources directly from CMS but there's a lot of other information out there especially when you are willing to go hunting for it from local MONHARQ instances, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, there are a number of different quality improvement initiatives at all different levels of government and the healthcare ecosystem. Here are some of my favorite sources for hospital level data which has good coverage across CMS certified hospitals in the US:

- **CMS Hospital Compare** - http://www.medicare.gov/hospitalcompare/Data/Measures-Displayed.html - this page shows the different measures data is available for. You can download the data from data.medicare.gov [here](https://data.medicare.gov/data/hospital-compare) and/or through data.cms.gov by searching through the data sets. You can programmatically access all the great data on data.cms.gov through Socrata APIs which are detailed at http://dev.socrata.com.
- I personally think hospital patient experience ([HCAHPS](http://www.hcahpsonline.org/home.aspx)) data should be considered in conjunction with other quality data and so I suggest checking out the HCAPS data which can be accessed at https://data.medicare.gov/Hospital-Compare/HCAHPS-Hospital/dgck-syfz
- **CMS Physician Compare** - https://data.medicare.gov/data/physician-compare - similar to CMS Hospital Compare but with less measures. Mainly PQRS data which is at https://data.medicare.gov/Physician-Compare/Physician-Quality-Reporting-System-PQRS-Group-Prac/ddiw-pgap
- **ACO Quality Data** - https://data.medicare.gov/Physician-Compare/Accountable-Care-Organization-ACO-Quality-Data/ytf2-4ept - this is sort of under the umbrella of the CMS Physician Compare data sets but I think it's worth noting separately too